# How to specify a specific product in udev hwdb file?

Tags: rhel, keyboard, udev

I'm trying to remap the buttons on a peripheral that incorrectly has its buttons mapped to F keys. To remedy this I'm trying to use a udev hwdb file to remap keys only on specif devices.

So far my rule looks like:

```
keyboard:usb:v11AAp*
 [remapping rules]
```

This rule works, but both the keyboard and peripheral are made by the same manufacturer, so I need to fill in the product as well. I've tried using the product specified in /proc/bus/input/devices and `udevadm info --attribute-walk --name=[path to input device] | grep idProduct` (these are both the same id, which is a good sign) but then the rule applies to neither the keyboard or peripheral.

The resulting looks like:

```
keyboard:usb:v11AAp11AA
 [remapping rules]
```

Is there something wrong with my syntax here? How does one properly define a hwdb rule for only a specific product?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only issue was that after the product ID the '*' is still required, so in the end the rule looked like:

```
keyboard:usb:v11AAp11AA*
 [remapping rules]
```

Simple syntax error.